# Why won't OS X let me rename a file?

Tags: osx, rm

I accidentally named a file `testIn2Post.py` rather than `testIn2post.py` (notice the different case for the letter "p") and have been unable to rename it, even after `rm`-ing the file in question. Notice that when I recreate the file with a lowercase "p" and then run `ls`, the file is created with a capital "p":

[image]

I expected to create a filename `testIn2post.py`, but I get `testIn2Post.py` (again, different case for the letter "p").

How can I force OS X to properly rename/create my file? It is causing issues when I try to import the module.

Comment: It would be inmensly useful if you show the actual error message when you try to rename/delete the file.

Comment: What filesystem are you using?  Unlike Linux, OSX normal filesystem is case-insensitive, is it not?  If so, then `testIn2Post.py` and `testIn2post.py` are the same file.

Comment: @Braiam as you can see from the image, there is no error message, just the wrong filename after touching (look carefully and see the difference in casing on the `p`'

Comment: @John1024, I figured OS X's case insensitivity was the source of the issue and am looking for a solution to this "caching" of the original name.

Comment: @Braiam, there is no error message. See Anthon's comment.

Comment: @Anthon exactly, what error is shown? OP doesn't present his attempts to rename or delete the file. How are we supposed to know where the problem is if we can't see the problem manifesting itself?

Comment: @Braiam, I didn't take a screenshot of my terminal when I created and then renamed the file because I saw no error at the time. I suppose you can downvote me because you find the question confusing, but I'm not sure how to be more clear. I created a file, tried to rename it, and that didn't work. Then I noticed that after `rm`-ing the file and `touch`-ing it, it had the old name, which I felt was significant. Sorry I can't show more.

Comment: @Braiam If you create a file by `touch abc` in an empty directory and then do `ls` and see a filename `xyz` you think that is normal? Not an error condition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There might be simpler ways, but when I have encounterd the Mac's filesystem to behave against my (Unix) expectations I moved the files that I need to a new directory, remove the old one and renamed the new directory to the old one.

```
cd ..
mkdir tmptest
mv test/*.py tmptest
rm -rf test
mv tmptest test
```

I am not sure what causes this except that it probably has to do with the underlying filesystem not being case-sensitive as John1024 already commented. It never happened often enough to me to care about finding a more efficient solution than this workaround.

Comment: Okay, this worked. I actually just `mv`-ed the file down a directory and then back up.